# Java SWIG: How to reorder input parameters for multi-argument typemaps

Tags: java, c++, swig

Say I have the following abstract C++ class from a 3rd party lib which I cannot change.

```
 class Foo : virtual public FooBase {
   public:
     virtual void bar(void *pBuffer, int64_t address, int64_t length) = 0;
 };
```

I want to be able to implement this class in Java using *directors*. The generated Java class should look something like this.

```
private class Foo extends FooBase {
  ...
  public void bar(long address, byte[] pBuffer) {...}
}
```

I have a typemap that looks like this

```
%typemap(in) (void *pBuffer, int64_t length) {
    $1 = (void*)(jenv)->GetByteArrayElements($input, NULL);
    $2 = (jenv)->GetArrayLength($input);
    if(!$1)
    {
        SWIG_JavaThrowException(jenv, SWIG_JavaOutOfMemoryError, "Failed to convert byte array.");
    }
}

%typemap(freearg) (void *pBuffer, int64_t length) {
    (jenv)->SetByteArrayRegion($input, 0, (jsize) $2,  (const jbyte*)$1);
    (jenv)->ReleaseByteArrayElements($input, (jbyte*)$1, 0);
}

%typemap(jni) (void *pBuffer, int64_t length) "jbyteArray"
%typemap(jtype) (void *pBuffer, int64_t length) "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) (void *pBuffer, int64_t length) "byte[]"
%typemap(javain) (void *pBuffer, int64_t length) "$javainput"
```

But it can only be applied if `Foo::bar`'s inputs has the order
`int_t address, void* pBuffer, int64_t length`.

Is it possible to rearrange the input parameters in `Foo::bar` in order for the multi-argument typemap to work?

Comment: easiest solution would be creating new class that extend Foo and deliver abstract method with reordered args that is called from overwritten

Comment: You should be able to pull a hack together that does the same thing, but doesn't use a multi arg typemap and sets `numinputs=0` on the `int64_t length` arg I think, but it'll be more fragile than the normal multi argument typemap mechanism. I'll do an answer over the weekend if nobody else gets a chance first.